# How to create new project with Visual Studio 2017 that will target .NET Core 2.1.6 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.1

When I'm trying to create new project (of any type) in Visual Studio 2017 I can target only major version of **2.1 .NET Core**, and from NuGet Package Manager it's not possible to update it to the latest version to **2.1.6 .NET Core**.

There is a point in NuGet Package Manager:
*Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK to which it belongs. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#updating-a-package)*
In "Learn more" is pointed that I need to install latest version of SDK, which I did, but anyway it's not possible to update existed nor create new project with latest version.

So the questions is how to do it?
Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, VS will use the latest version of the SDK that is installed on your box (see footnote regarding previews).  If you create a project targeting 2.1 and you have both the 2.1.5 and 2.1.6 SDKs installed, it will use 2.1.6.

If you have an existing project that was created from 2.1.5, VS will use the tools from 2.1.6 to build and run your project *unless you pin your tooling with a global.json file*.  In most cases (more so for 2.0+), a newer SDK should be fine even if you're still targeting a lower netcore framework version.

If you have explicit version references in your project, you will still need to update your them yourself, VS does not do that today.

You may notice that in ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, there is no version for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App PackageRference (it's implicit).  To quote from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> When the version is not specified, an implicit version is specified by the SDK, that is, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.

However, there are a train of GitHub issues ([1](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3292), [2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3307)) showing that this has been debated and may change at some point.

Footnote:

If you install a preview version of the .NET Core SDK, VS may or may not use it depending on this setting:
[image: Tools/Options checkbox named 'Use previews of the .NET Core SDK']

By default, if you are using a Release version of VS, this will be unchecked.  If you are using a Preview version of VS, this will be checked by default.  You can always toggle it yourself depending on the behavior you want.